# CSS numeric font style - One line height

Tags: css, fonts

I have a question regarding one of google web fonts.
Font which i mean is 'Alegreya Sans'

By default numbers are not aligned in same way... Somehow designer send me zeplin file where he is using same font with equal line heights.

You can see here what i mean (its my default html style):

[image: default]

This is how it looks on design:

[image]

And this is what i achived with css right now using:

```
font-variant: diagonal-fractions;
```

[image]

But problem in this solution is - numbers are to small right now... I cant change font size, because its mixed sometimes with letters.
Once in another project I fixed it somehow with css, but i cant remember how I did it. There was some css property which fix this issue.

Comment: Looks like that font has some old style numerals. Some fonts like Georgia have this baked in. Nor sure what can be done but try `font-variant-numeric: normal;` to see if it helps…

Comment: @chriskirknielsen I allready tried it... But works only with diagonal-fractions - but then numbers are too small

Comment: That's normal, diagonal fraction numbers are supposed to fit in smaller spaces. You might want to ask your designer if they applied any changes to the numbers. Have you tried `font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums;` as well? All numbers will take up the same amount of space but they might look "aligned" like you are wishing for.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen I tried all possibilities with font-variant, font-variant-numeric etc. Only diagonal fractions looks like removing "old style numerals"

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so i have answer for my question.
Google web fonts has limited font features when we using it from google cdn - i guess to make it lighter...

So i decided to download this font as desktop font, and then from .ttf files i generated webfont using transfonter.

I simply used

```
font-variant-numeric: lining-nums;
```

And font looks perfect now!